# Ruby on rails - Add multiple record from new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, controller, nested-forms

In my application I have `Domain` model that have these columns: `name`, `link`, `description`.

Currently my application works as I can only add **one** domain at a time (from `new action`). What I am looking for is to be able to add as many domains as I want from the same form/page.

I have used `nested_forms` before but usually its `nested_attributes` for another model.

How am I able to have `nested_forms` for same model or if there is any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, but not in a RESTful way. There are some hacks to do it, But I don't recommend and best way would be to do `associations` and adding  `nested_attributes` to it.